# DataTables Infinite + automatic data refresh

Tags: javascript, datatables

Is it possible to reload dataTable within infinite pagination keeping user sort, position in table?
I tried using fnReloadAjax plugin, but every time refresh is executed, all data is reloaded and previous position in table is lost.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you wanting to connect to Ajax data and requery the data keeping the user offset/sort etc or do you want to refresh the page each time and store the users previous state? DataTables supports ajax and when requesting the ajax source can pass the users table state as part of the querystring so you know how many rows to skip/return during server processing. I'd consider using the ajax functionality as it can provide a very slick experience for the user

Comment: Yes, i want to connect ajax data, keeping sort/offset and i want infinite scroll connected with fnReloadAjax, which refresh the table each X seconds.

Comment: I've added something I did like this to my blog: http://charlespockert.wordpress.com/2013/10/31/mvc4-and-jquery-datatables/ - it doesn't have infinite scroll though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible . You need to set "bStateSave": true in datatable initialization.It uses cookies on client side to save table state

Source :http://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html